# Transaction scope issue in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, transactionscope

> Transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. Transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements

I am getting the above error, when I try to save through EF6 in a transaction. 
I am updating data in a table and I have a trigger on update for that table. So, when I disable the trigger everything works fine, but when I enable the trigger I get the above mentioned error.

I tried increasing **timeout** and **suppressing the transaction**, but no luck..

My transaction code looks like this:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    var obj = this._objRepo.GetobjCodesByName("xxxxxx");
    obj.CodeName = "eeee";

    this._context.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Complete();

    return Code;
}
```

Any workaround?

Comment: can you show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need to use Transaction at all.B'cos you have only one transaction.Then you don't need to use `TransactionScope()`.If you use it unnecessary,it'll give extra overhead to your saving process.In other words it causes to slowdown the operation.

You can try as shown below without using `TransactionScope()`.

```
using (var _context= new YourDBEntities())
{
   //your update code

   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the full scope of the code. But based on the code snippet posted in your question, the problem is at `_objRepo.GetobjCodesByName("xxxxxx");`

You need to suppress your selects from transaction scope. In SQL Server 2005 and above, even when you use with(nolock), locks are still created on those tables the select touches.

To address this situation, you need to rewrite the code as below

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(TransactionScope tsSuppressed = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) 
    {
        var obj = this._objRepo.GetobjCodesByName("xxxxxx");
        obj.CodeName = "eeee";
    }

    this._context.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Complete();

    return Code;
}
```

Hope this helps.